# Preselected HTML Dropdown has a show/hide script, but only works on page and not via URL Parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Newcomer here, I've been learning from this community a lot and finally came to a sort of a small problem.

So right now I have a html dropdown option/selector.

On that selector's ID I have a code that grabs the URL Parameter and assigns the correct option, and it works. If you put in the right url parameter it  takes you to the page and preselects the option. I also have a code that shows or hides sections based on the selection, using a mix of IDs and Classes as it's a complicated approach.

```
<script>    
$(function() {
      $('#all-content').change(function(){
        $('.hide-knowledgecenter').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Now the problem is that, using the URL parameter the show/hide script doesn't run based on the preselected option, it just shows the preselected option but it won't run the code.

this is the preselect code. I don't know if it's a hiearchy problem or what but i can't seem to get it to work. Should the preselect code be global to the whole website or only loaded on this specific page? Is there one code that should go first then the second? Or is it something completely else?

```
<script>
var val = location.href.match(/[?&]all-content=(.*?)(?:$|&)/)[1];   // get params from URL
$('#all-content').val(val);   //  assign URL param to select field
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply added

```
}).triggerHandler('change');
```

to the bottom of the filter code and it loaded along with the preloader.